# What are the two precondition on Binary search?

Tags: c, binary-search

i have been asked in an interview what are the two preconditions of the binary search .I have told them array should be sorted in ascending order but i didn't know what could be the second precondition of binary search?

Anyone can tell me about the second precondition of Binary search?

Comment: seems like a silly question from interview panel - you should ask them because you might learn something useful about the prospective employer

Comment: I'm fearing we are just missing context information here. I bet the real answer was something like `"The array elements must already be sorted according the same comparison predicate` *AND* (dadabing!) `the mutex for the array should be locked"` <whistles/>

Comment: I think you need: a sorted data structure and that data structure must have `O(1)` indexed access

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - looking at the answers, it's not that silly after all. Apparently people are not so strong on algorithms and data structures even with some substantial programming experience (or at least reputation on this site...)

Answer (score 4):

Data <strike>Array</strike> should be sorted, and sorted in the **right** order. I.e.: if its sorted in ascending order when the binary search assumes descending order - it won't work.

Some clarifications, as it seems that people forgot their Algorithms 101.

Precondition is a condition, that if not met - the algorithm is not required to provide the correct result.

Random access is not a precondition for a binary search algorithm, as it can and should return the correct answer even if the random access is not available (Binary Search Trees rely on that).

less-than operator certainly doesn't have to be defined, as it is a language-specific implementation detail. But it is close to the truth.

Data structure **must** be sorted ([weak-ordered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering)) for any search other than linear to work.

Data structure must be sorted in the **same** order as the one assumed by the binary search algorithm. As I mentioned, if the data is sorted in the ascending order, like the OP said, it doesn't mean that the binary search will provide the correct result, if the search is built for descending order, for example. There are many orders, ascending, descending, lexicographic, etc etc.

When you use a binary search function you must ensure that the input is sorted, and sorted to the order you're going to use. If these two are not met - you're not required to provide correct result.

Comment: I think this is all summarized in "sorted" as in the question.

Comment: @nightcracker - no. Sorted means they're sorted in **some** order.

Comment: @littleadv, in fact the opposite, **ordered** means *sorted in some order** In fact what nightcracker means to say is that this summarizes to the list being "ordered" not sorted. To help you understand, a quadtree is a sorting of data but is not at all an ordering.

Comment: hi thanks a lot for the input, how about this: "The data must be able to be compared according to the search comparison algorithm" is this considered to be a precondition for binary search?

Comment: what is random access, please explain why it is not a precondition. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

There is a good run-down of the pre-conditions of binary search [here](http://reprog.wordpress.com/2010/04/30/writing-correct-code-part-3-preconditions-and-postconditions-binary-search-part-4c/):

> The array must be sorted in ascending order according to the ordering
>   used by the comparisons in the search function.

The author only specifies one pre-condition but I expect you could break it down to 2 conditions that are related to each other...

- Must be sorted in **ascending or descending order**, depending on your search algorithm
- Input must be **compatible with the comparison** algorithm

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that you need random access for the binary search to be efficient. Or at least the array should be iterable multiple times.

Comment: Array by definition has random access.

Comment: @littleadv: You don't know for sure that the original question specified "array".

Comment: You can run binary search without random access, and still get the correct results. Inefficient? Maybe. But not a precondition.

Comment: @littleadv: Did I state anything else? Are you just trying to downvote me to have your answer higher?

Comment: Sorry, my comment was to @caf. Binary search can be implemented using BST's, for example, which definitely don't have random access, and in fact are not arrays at all.

Comment: @littleadv: That's what caf was probably pointing to. And me too.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm confused. The question was "what are the two preconditions on Binary Search", what were you trying to answer to?

Answer (score 0):

The elements must have the less-than operator defined.

Comment: That's implicit in the array being ordered

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Really? The program or function could for example accept already sorted input.

Comment: I think what David is saying is that if the first condition is satisfied (i.e. that the collection is already sorted), it can only have met this condition by virtue of having a less-than operator already defined.  But I like your answer, provided by "defined" you mean that the operator is actually accessible (callable) from real code.  In many languages you can have operator< private, or simply not declared at all, even though "we know what it is."

Comment: Yes, but I think nightcracker was giving a very general answer anyway. :)

Comment: @nightcracker: that seems to be specific to c++, for one thing, in C, the less-than operator can't even be defined for all types. Binary search may has many implementations, most of which allow a custom comparison predicate. IOW that's not a pre-condition, that's an implementation detail

Comment: The compare function might very well not be in scope.

Comment: Eehm, with __operator__ I mean less than (`<`) in general. Not necessarily an overloaded one.

Answer (score 0):

Elements need to be in a sorted array, so I guess they mean

1) The elements are in an array (or in any data structure that enables indexed access).

2) The storage is sorted according to the compare function.

Comment: Sorted and fast access to the elements. Binary search on a linked list is pointless, for example.

Comment: Fast is useful, but not necessary. And it is relative, e.g. if you have a very complex compare function that's a magnitude slower than the element access.

Comment: BST's don't have indexed access.

Answer (score 0):

That means

1. Arrray must be sorted
2. Sorting algorithm used